# Find topics in Machine learning in gcloud

Tags: artificial-intelligence, gcloud, topic-modeling

I'm new in machine learning I see some services on Google Cloud platform related to A.I I think these are easy to use.

Here is what I need I have around 20K paragraphs (3 or 4 line) I need to find the most matching paragraph according to user question. User ask any question or type any sentence I need to find the most similar paragraph related to this user sentence how can I do that. What Services I need to achieve this I want to use Google Cloud platform. is it possible in gcloud if yes then how.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start your journey looking through the GCP [AI & ML](https://cloud.google.com/products/ai) product list. Narrowing down the initial request and seeking for a best match affording your custom use scenario, I would advice to get more details about [GCP AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/automl) products, offering a variety of complete solution for a generic machine learning models such as AutoML [Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs) model specifically designed for a document and text analysis tasks.

I would encourage you to start with *AutoML Natural Language* beginner's [guide](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/beginners-guide) to get more context, having look at features and capabilities like of *Classification*, *Entity extraction*, *Sentiment analysis* training [approaches](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/features#entity_extraction).

As from the developers perspective, Cloud AutoML Natural Language supports a [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/libraries/client-libraries) for most known programming languages and offers good [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest) documentation though.